# How to retrieve value in ObjecStore using MEL

Tags: mule, dataweave

I need to retrieve object store value in DataWeaveComponent. Some of the suggestions given were to store the value in flowvariable and use it. Well it does not work in my case, Because I am transforming a collection of 1000 records in DataWeave. For each record, I need to fetch the value from object store and store it to a field. Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a flow that does what you want and then use the [lookup](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation#functions-and-lambdas) function to execute it from DataWeave.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this
1.Storing the entire value from object store to a flowVars and access it,Dont create multiple variable foe each time

2.Create lookup in data weave then in the lookup flow retrive the object store content.But you will invoke object store every single time.

My suggestion is to fetch the content of Obj store and add it to flowVars.
Please let me know in comment if need further clarification.